# Object hidden under Map [React]

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm using google-map-react, and my problem is that dropMenu element is hidden under map im my app. How can I change it ??

Screen:
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can play with `z-index` property for the menu. Read further here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: I used zindex on dropmenu. Event 9999999 didnt help, but i cant find how to set it on map..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```html
<div className="dropdown-menu />
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  position: relative; /* or absolute */
  z-index: 1000;
}
```